# Windows 7 change aspect ratio

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, user-interface

My computer has Windows 7 installed. The display is widescreen, but I need to use some legacy programs which were designed for 4:3 monitors. Right now the program works in full screen, but the UI is stretched to fit the wider monitor. This is incredibly frustrating, and I would like it to display with proper proportions and black boxes on the sides of the screen. I tried right-clicking the desktop and selecting "screen resolution", but all the choices listed there are 16:9. How can I force windows to use a 4:3 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to your monitor...
The reason your screen is getting stretched is because the monitor does not support the 4:3 format.

If you plug-in an old monitor with the original 4:3 format you should be good to go.

There's however a few wide screen monitors on the market that supports changing aspect ratio, if your looking for one check the specification before purchasing.